# Adding information of a shapefile to a GPS coordinate

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, fields-attributes, gps

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1 and I am currently trying to add information to a GPS coordinate. This coordinate (red) lies within a shape from a shapefile, and the shapefile as some attributes (yellow box). I want to match these attribute to the GPS file (blue arrow).

I tried to illustrate this with the picture bellow and would be very glad if someone could help me with this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click your layer in the table of contents, you can choose to Join data by spatial location. Alternatively, you can use the Spatial Join tool.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/about-joining-the-attributes-of-features-by-their-location.htm

Comment: That just worked perfectly. Cheers on you! Thanks!